# How to remove the json key value with JSonPath in java

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I know it could be a duplicate, but still posting my question as i could not find the exact answer what i am looking for. I am having an json object (or string) like below.

```
String str = "{
    "status" : {
        "timestamp" : "2020-04-30T01:00:00 000Z"
        "error" : 0,
        "error_message" : null,
        "execution" : "completed"
    }
}
";
```

I will get the a same kind of response from my REST API testing, but after each call the 'timestamp' key will be having a dynamic date and time value with the time respect to the call made. And here i compare my expect json with the actual json as a whole sting comparison using JSONAssert. As the timestamp value is different it always fails for me.

So my question is before i do any comparison, i would like to remove the 'timestamp' key and its value from json to compare and so it will pass my case. I tried by using JsonPath also, but did not works. Any help on this please?

Answer (score 0):

JSONAssert allow you to make a customized comparator while doing asserts [1].

In your case it's easy as:

```
JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedJson,
                        actualJson,
                        new CustomComparator(JSONCompareMode.LENIENT,
                                            skips("status.timestamp","another.json.path", ...)));

private static Customization[] skips(String... jsonPaths) {
    return Arrays.stream(jsonPaths)
                 .map(jsonPath -> Customization.customization(jsonPath, (o1, o2) -> true))
                 .toArray(Customization[]::new);
}
```

Here we are defining `CustomComparator`, with `customization` which takes JSONPath (`status.timestamp`) and takes a `ValueMatcher` (lambda) which compares two values for that specific JSONPath.

In our case we will always return `true`, which will effectively skips the value (no matter with what we are comparing that value it's always true).

Edit: As you can see `CustomComparator`'s constructor takes `varargs` of `Customization`s, hence you can provide more than one field to be ignore from comparison.

---

[1] http://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org/apidocs/org/skyscreamer/jsonassert/Customization.html

[2] http://jsonassert.skyscreamer.org/apidocs/org/skyscreamer/jsonassert/comparator/CustomComparator.html

Comment: thanks for the answer. Let me look into it. But this solution is for just skipping one key. But what if i have to skip multiple keys on the json during my comparison? sometimes, the there are other fields which i need to skip during comparison which may be in other jsonpaths.

Comment: There's no problem with adding more `Customization`s, see edited answer.